# Javascript Sum with Sum displayed

Tags: javascript, integer, sum

So I have to accept an integer from the user and later add that integer plus every number under it until we get to `+ 0` and display all that work and get the sum total, how do I do that. For example, if the user inputs the integer 10, it should display on the document :

```
10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 55
```

Thanks, hope this makes sense.

This is what I have so far :

```
    <script>
    //Variable declarations
    var i;
    i = Number(prompt("Enter an integer greater than zero:"));
    if ( i <= 0 ) {
        document.write("<p>Invalid Input</p>");
    }
    else {
        var start = i;
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = start; i > 0; i--)
        {
            total += i;
        }
            document.write( total );
    }

</script>
```

Comment: OK, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: What you have tried to achieve this ?

Comment: [you haven't shown what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). If you need a programmer to write code for you, I would suggest hiring one. otherwise, you'll need to include a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, Yeah I just did

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

```js
var start = 10;
var total = 0;
var flow = "";

for(var i = start; i > 0; i--)
{
 total += i;
    flow += i + " + ";
}

flow = flow.substring(0, flow.length - 2);
flow += " = " + total;

$("#flow").html(flow);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="flow"></span>
```

**EDIT**
Changed the code to output the workflow. And thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful, thanks. I just need to know now how to display the sum work on the document. Like actually have the "10 + 9 + ... = 55" on the document not just the total, thank you so much though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
      for (var i = start; i > 0; i--)
    {
        document.write(i+"+");

    }
        document.write("="+total );
```